# Curl-convert to a simple http request?

Tags: http, post, curl, lua

I have some `curl` request, in which i would like to build from it a basic `POST` request-authenticated (with headers etc), i couldn't find any tool that convert that :

```
curl -X POST 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/Calls.json' \
--data-urlencode 'To=xxxxxxx65542'  \
--data-urlencode 'From=+xxxxxxx4215'  \
-d 'Url=https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01'  \
-d 'Method=GET'  \
-d 'FallbackMethod=GET'  \
-d 'StatusCallbackMethod=GET'  \
-d 'Record=false' \
-u ACbe68cddxxxxxxxxxxxx3aba243cc4cdb:0f442xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

So how would my POST request should look like ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to convert the above curl request to?  Not sure thats clear.

Comment: I am having some api , that shows me a curl code to do something. than, i have some hardware device, that should send a POST request, but its not running curl, so i have to take that curl code, and make from it a full basic POST request ,that i can run for example in this site :https://www.hurl.it . so how would i take this curl code, and create from it the right fields to send a request using that website for instance ?

Comment: So you have a hardware device that cannot run curl that you want to make the HTTP request from?  Do I have that right?  What platform or programming language is the hardware device running?

Comment: @DevinRader YES EXACTLY. It runs lua ..

Comment: Lua itself has no network IO so you have to use external library. So which one you use? May be you can just use curl binding?

Comment: Doing a bit of research it looks like the LuaSocket library might help you make the http request.  http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the cURL man page :

> -H, --header  (HTTP)  Extra  header  to use when getting a web page. You may specify any number of extra headers. Note that if you
>   should add a custom header that has the same name as one of the
>   internal ones curl would use,  your  externally  set header  will  be 
>   used instead of the internal one. This allows you to make even
>   trickier stuff than curl would nor‐ mally do. You should not replace
>   internally set headers without knowing perfectly well what you're
>   doing. Remove  an internal  header  by  giving a replacement without
>   content on the right side of the colon, as in: -H "Host:". If you send
>   the custom header with no-value then its header must be terminated
>   with a  semicolon,  such  as  -H  "X-Custom- Header;" to send
>   "X-Custom-Header:".
>
> curl will make sure that each header you add/replace is sent with the
>   proper end-of-line marker, you should thus not add that as a part of
>   the header content: do not add newlines or carriage returns, they will
>   only mess things up for you.
>
> See also the -A, --user-agent and -e, --referer options.
>
> This option can be used multiple times to add/replace/remove multiple
>   headers.

Amazon AWS makes heavy use of headers for authentication. A quick Google should lead to many examples such as this one from http://tmont.com/blargh/2014/1/uploading-to-s3-in-bash  :

```
  curl -X PUT -T "${file}" \
  -H "Host: ${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com" \
  -H "Date: ${dateValue}" \
  -H "Content-Type: ${contentType}" \
  -H "Authorization: AWS ${s3Key}:${signature}" \
  https://${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/${file}
```

All you need to do is adapt the AWS examples for your twilio use.

To make the example into a POST, just change PUT to POST and add your POST fields *-d "field1=val1&field2=val2&field3=val3"*

Comment: I am not sure what is the bottom line of your answer. how exactly would my request look alike ??

Comment: @Curnelious  Please clarify your question.  If my answer was not correct then obviously I'm not sure what you are trying to ask ?

Answer (score 2):

Okay so i was trying to figure out how to send a text message from an ESP8266 nodeMcu v0.9 module. It is capable of working like an arduino with the arduino ide 1.6.4.

Anyways, I found http://textbelt.com and it only shows a simple CURL way of sending the text message.

This is the CURL message it wants you to send

```
$ curl -X POST http://textbelt.com/text \ -d number=5551234567 \ -d "message=I sent this message for free with textbelt.com"
```

So to convert to a normal HTTP POST command i did the following. (this works in Arduino IDE)
number and message are String objects.

```
String messageToSend = "number="+number+"&message="+message;

client.print("POST /text HTTP/1.1\r\n");
client.print("Host: textbelt.com\r\n");
client.print("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
client.print("Content-Length: ");
client.print(messageToSend.length());
client.print("\r\n\r\n");
client.print(messageToSend);
```

At first i tried without the Content-Type but that didn't seem to work. So i had to add the type of content i was sending as well.

If you were to monitor the network traffic with say WireShark you would see

```
POST /text HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: textbelt.com\r\n
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n
Content-Length: 48\r\n
\r\n
number=5551234567&message=this is a text message
```

I may have been able to use less text with text/plain as the content-type but i think it may need the application urlencoded type to work.

Hope this helps someone else trying to convert curl to http.

Answer (score -1):

You can specify the headers using `--header` and the type of request (POST) by using `-X` / `--request` parameters.

Example:

```
curl --request POST --header "X-MyHeader: MyAuthenticatedHeader" www.stackoverflow.com
```

In your case it should be:

```
curl -X POST 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/Calls.json' \
--header 'X-MyHeader: MyAuthenticatedHeader' \
--data-urlencode 'To=xxxxxxx65542'  \
--data-urlencode 'From=+xxxxxxx4215'  \
-d 'Url=https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01'  \
-d 'Method=GET'  \
-d 'FallbackMethod=GET'  \
-d 'StatusCallbackMethod=GET'  \
-d 'Record=false' \
-u ACbe68cddxxxxxxxxxxxx3aba243cc4cdb:0f442xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: You just showed me the same thing again, i dont understand from your answer how exactly should my post request look like ?

Comment: The above curl code is exactly what you want. The -X POST is for making post request and the --header 'yourheaders' is to send the headers. Are you looking for PHP code? or are you just using the command line curl. If you are using command line then the above is sufficient. If you are using it in your PHP or ASP.net app then you should change your question.

Comment: I am having some api , that shows me a curl code to do something. than, i have some hardware device, that should send a POST request, but its not running curl, so i have to take that curl code, and make from it a full POST request ,that i can run for example in this site :https://www.hurl.it . so how would i take this curl code, and create from it the right fields to send a request using that website for instance ?

Comment: Next time do clarify the exact scenario. You question lack the mention of lua & all the complexities of your situation. Now which programming language will you be using? If you are also going to be using lua then that hardware must have an API to work with, you must use that API to get that POST request and then use a curl library like 'LuaCURL' instead of running the request using [hurl.it](https://www.hurl.it).
Now don't ask for how to interact with that API, check it's documentation.